# Entity Framework: configuring One to Zero or One with own Ids

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, entity-relationship

This is for EF 6. So I have these 2 objects: `User` can have 0 or 1 `Mechanic`:

```
public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual Mechanic Mechanic { get; set; }
}

public class Mechanic
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Key, ForeignKey("User")]
    public int UserId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public virtual User User { get; set; }
}
```

This is the only way I found to go about it when I need its own `Id` in `Mechanic` object, but apparently it cannot serve as a Primary Key, so I'm just making it an auto-incremented identity column. Now this is a good work-around for 1 to 0 or 1 relationship.

However, there are flaws. I need to have another object `PricePackages` that is dependent on `Mechanic`, so now my objects are:

```
public partial class Mechanic
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Key, ForeignKey("User")]
    public int UserId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public virtual User User { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<PricePackage> PricePackages { get; set; }
}

public class PricePackage
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Mechanic")]
    public int MechanicId { get; set; }

    public virtual Mechanic Mechanic { get; set; }
}
```

This works fine, however when I insert into `PricePackage`, the `MechanicId` is actually a `Mechanic.UserId`, and not `Mechanic.Id` that I want. How do I fix that?

Comment: Mechanic.Id is not the primary key so you can't setup a relationship to it.

Comment: @SteveGreene right, so how can I go about it to achieve what I want? Possibly restructure the objects somehow so `User` still has 0 or 1 `Mechanic` and so I can use `Mechanic.Id` as a foreign key for other objects?

Comment: @dima technically your primary key is UserId, what is wrong with using that in your PricePackage table?

Comment: @DavidLee yes, I made `UserId` a primary key for `Mechanic` because otherwise EF will complain about my 1 to 0 or 1 relationship (EF requires that both objects/tables have to share the primary key) and it worked until I needed to add another object `PricePackage` that would depend on `Mechanic`... to answer your question, technically there is nothing wrong except for business and personal preferences to use `Mechanic.Id` as a foreign key and not `Mechanic.UserId`